# Lattice constant for ternary compound $\mathrm{In}_{0.532}\mathrm{Ga}_{0.468}\mathrm{As}$

Tags: solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics

I am currently studying *Physics of Photonic Devices*, second edition, by Shun Lien Chuang. Chapter **1.3 The Field of Optoelectronics** says the following when discussing semiconductor physics:

> For example, by controlling the mole fraction of gallium and indium in an $\mathrm{In}_{1 - x}\mathrm{Ga}_{x}\mathrm{As}$ material, a wide tunable range of band gap is possible because $\mathrm{InAs}$ has a $0.354 \ \text{eV}$ band gap and $\mathrm{GaAs}$ has a $1.424 \ \text{eV}$ band gap at room temperature. The lattice constant of the ternary alloy has a linear dependence on the mole fraction
> $$a(\mathrm{A}_x\mathrm{B}_{1 - x}\mathrm{C}) = xa(\mathrm{AC}) + (1 - x)a(\mathrm{BC}) \tag{1.3.1}$$
> where $a(\mathrm{AC})$ is the lattice constant of the binary compound $\mathrm{AC}$ and $a(\mathrm{BC})$ is that of the compound $\mathrm{BC}$. This linear interpolation formula works very well for the lattice constant, but not for the band gap. For the band-gap dependence, a quadratic dependence on the mole fraction $x$ is usually required
> $$E_g(\mathrm{A}_x\mathrm{B}_{1 - x}\mathrm{C} = x E_g(\mathrm{AC}) + (1 - x)E_g(\mathrm{BC}) - bx(1 - x) \tag{1.3.2}$$
> where $b$ is called the bowing parameter because it causes a deviation of the ternary band-gap energy away from a linear interpolation of the two band-gap energies of the binary compounds. Figure 1.9 plots the band-gap energy at $T = 0 \text{K}$ as a function of the lattice constant for many binary and ternary compound semiconductors. For example, $\mathrm{GaAs}$ has a band gap of $1.519 \ \text{eV}$ at low temperature and a lattice constant of $5.6533 \ \mathring{\mathrm{A}}$, whereas $\mathrm{InAs}$ has a band gap of $0.417 \ \text{eV}$ and a lattice constant of $6.0584 \ \mathring{\mathrm{A}}$, as indicated. A ternary $\mathrm{In}_{1 - x} \mathrm{Ga}_x \mathrm{As}$ compound has the two end points at $\mathrm{GaAs}$ ($x = 0$) and $\mathrm{InAs}$ ($x = 1$) and its band gap has a slight downward bowing below a linear interpolation. At $x = 0.468$, the $\mathrm{In}_{0.532}\mathrm{Ga}_{0.468}\mathrm{As}$ alloy has a lattice constant matched to that of the $\mathrm{InP}$ ($5.8688 \ \mathring{\mathrm{A}}$).
> [image]

For the ternary compound $\mathrm{In}_{0.532}\mathrm{Ga}_{0.468}\mathrm{As}$, how did the author  ascertain the lattice constant of $5.8688 \ \mathring{\mathrm{A}}$? It is clear how this is done for the binary compounds using figure 1.9, but I don't understand how it was done for $\mathrm{In}_{0.532}\mathrm{Ga}_{0.468}\mathrm{As}$. Did the author look this up using some other (not presented) graph?

I would greatly appreciate it if people would please take the time to clarify this.

Comment: Linear interpolation between the lattice constants of pure GaAs and pure InAs.

Comment: @JonCuster Thanks for the comment, Jon. Using the linear interpolation formula for $\mathrm{GaAs}$ and $\mathrm{InAs}$, we get $(0.468)(6.0584) + (0.532)(5.6533) = 5.84288 \ \mathring{\mathrm{A}} \not= 5.8688 \ \mathring{\mathrm{A}}$. Perhaps the author's value is an empirical one, rather than calculated?

Comment: InAs has the larger lattice constant (6.0584) and the larger concentration (0.532). Recalculate

Comment: @JonCuster Ahh, yes: $(0.532)(6.0584) + (0.468)(5.6533) = 5.8688 \ \mathring{\mathrm{A}}$ . Thanks for taking the time to clarify this.